# Pass query string when user is redirected to login

Tags: cakephp

I have a CakePHP website at the following url: http://driz.co.uk/

When a user (me) tries to access the portfolio admin at http://driz.co.uk/admin/portfolio/ they are automatically taken to the admin login at http://driz.co.uk/admin/login because the admin methods all require authentication.

What I want to do is pass the query string of the last page as well so when that redirect happens it will say this in the URL: http://driz.co.uk/admin/login?continue=/admin/portfolio/

How would I do this?

I've tried:

```
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array(
            'admin' => true,
            'prefix'=> 'admin',
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login',
            '?' => array('continue' => $this->referer())
        );
```

But that just causes a redirect loop (not sure why it's even trying to do a redirect :/

**Note: I know CakePHP automatically redirects the user after successful login BUT I want to add the query string as I'm using it for extra jazz in the app.**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cake automatically (if I recall) returns you to page you attempted to access after logging in, unless you mess with `$this->Auth->redirectLogin`.

You might have luck with this in a before filter:

```
$this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller'=>'users',
                                 'action'=>'login', 
                                 '?' => array('continue'=>'/' .
                                    strtolower($this->name) . '/' .
                                    $this->action), 'admin'=>false);
```

(dodgy line breaks added by me).

This will produce:

`site.com/admin/login?continue=%2Fcontroller%2Faction`
which is equivalent, more or less, to what you require.

You may or may not need/want `admin=>false`.

essentially this appends the current controller name and action to the `loginAction` redirect. Probably a bit of a dodgy hack 
I do not know how to prevent cake encoding the slashes

Comment: That causes this on the URL: `http://driz.co.uk/admin/login?continue=%2Fusers%2Fadmin_login` and then throws an error about a redirect loop

Answer (score 1):

In login() function, you can get the last page at `$this->Session->read('Auth.redirect');` So no need to add it in the url.